# Invariance of lagrangian under point transformation and symmetry of second derivatives

Tags: calculus-of-variations

I was trying to show an invariance, the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860594/invariance-of-lagrangian-under-point-transformation/3198368). But I can't understand a step. We have $q_{i}=q_{i}\left(s_{1},\dots,s_{n},t\right)$, then

$$\dot{q}_{i}= \frac{dq_i}{\text{dt}}
 =\sum_{j}\frac{\partial q_{i}}{\partial s_{j}}\frac{d s_{j}}{d t}+\frac{\partial q_{i}}{\partial t}
 =\sum_{j}\frac{\partial q_{i}}{\partial s_{j}}\dot{s}_{j}+\frac{\partial q_{i}}{\partial t}$$
But I can't understand how I reach in:
$$\frac{\partial\dot{q}_{i}}{\partial\dot{s}_{j}}=\frac{\partial q_{i}}{\partial s_{j}}$$

I thought about apply the chain rule:

$$\frac{\partial\dot{q}_{i}}{\partial\dot{s}_{k}}=\sum_{j}\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{s}_{k}}\left(\frac{\partial q_{i}}{\partial s_{j}}\dot{s}_{j}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{s}_{k}}\left(\frac{\partial q_{i}}{\partial t}\right)
 =\sum_{j}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{s}_{k}}\left(\frac{\partial q_{i}}{\partial s_{j}}\right)\dot{s}_{j}+\frac{\partial q_{i}}{\partial s_{j}}\frac{\partial\dot{s}_{j}}{\partial\dot{s}_{k}}\right]+\frac{\partial}{\partial\dot{s}_{k}}\left(\frac{\partial q_{j}}{\partial t}\right)$$

I think that the second term is just $\frac{\partial\dot{s}_{j}}{\partial\dot{s}_{k}}=\delta_{jk}$, and if the second partial derivative has continuous, I can change the order, so how $\frac{\partial q_{i}}{\partial\dot{s}_{j}}=0$, I reach my goal. I am right?

Comment: I edited it because I was a little confused about the requirements to change the sequence of the partials derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to use is that partial derivatives commute (i.e. we can switch their order) and you have $q_i$ in terms of variables that do not include $\dot{s_k}$. The third term is then equal to zero.

Comment: I was worried about the requirements that are needed to partial derivatives commute. But I was reading the Schwarz integrability condition, and basically, the condition is that exists a continuous second partial derivative. So I think that I don't need to worry so much about this.

Comment: Yep, this existence is one of the assumptions we make in the Lagrangian invariance proof

Comment: Thank you. This solve my question ahha